# Hatched Pattern Brush or Striped pattern in XAML Windows pHone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get hatched pattern to fill inside a rectangle in Windows Phone application. I am trying code of WPF given here

[WPF code for Hatched pattern in XAML](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.in/2007/06/creating-hatched-patterned-brush-in-wpf.html)
    Is there any way except to use image to fill inside of a rectangle with hatched pattern brush?